# How to mock kotlin map function?

Tags: android, kotlin, mocking

I'm trying to stub a kotlin extension `.map`:

```
private fun stubGetUsers(users: List<User>) {
   val genericRawResult = mock<GenericRawResults<User>>()
   whenever(genericRawResult.map { User() }).thenReturn(users)

   usersDao.stub { on { it.queryRaw("", RawRowMapper { _, _ -> User() }) }.doReturn(genericRawResult) }
}
```

When I run the test, I'm getting a `NullPointerException`:

```
public inline fun <T, R, C : MutableCollection<in R>> Iterable<T>.mapTo(destination: C, transform: (T) -> R): C {
    for (item in this)
        destination.add(transform(item))
    return destination
}
```

at line: `for (item in this)`

So I tried to mock the `_Collections.kt` class `mapTo` function:

```
val destination = arrayListOf<User>()

whenever<List<User>>(genericRawResult.mapTo(destination) { User() }).thenReturn(destination)
```

But still getting the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.UserRepositoryTest.stubGetUsers(UserRepositoryTest.kt:144)
    at com.myapp.UserRepositoryTest.testGetAllUsers(UserRepositoryTest.kt:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

In order to get a detailed error, I've made the following changes:

```
genericRawResult.stub { onGeneric { it.mapTo(arrayListOf()) { User() } }.doReturn(arrayListOf()) }
genericRawResult.stub { on { it.map { User() } }.doReturn(users) }
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
ArrayList cannot be returned by iterator()
iterator() should return Iterator
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

Comment: Is `GenericRawResults` an interface, or does it extend a collection type? You should probably model it as an interface and have an implementation that delegates to a collection, in which case mocking `GenericRawResults.map` would be trivial.

Comment: Yes, it's an interface from an ORM Library: https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/GenericRawResults.html

This interface implements another Java Interface: `Iterable`, that's why I have access to the Kotlin's `Collection` map function.

Comment: See if you can change the code that depends on `GenericRawResults` to depend on `Iterable` instead, you'll have a much easier time mocking `Iterable`.